# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage on iPad2 is too slow ,it needs almost 30 ms, too crazy

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es

I use opengl es to display bgr24 data on iPad, I am new about opengl es ,so in display video part I use code from RosyWriter one APPLE sample. It works, but the CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage function cost more than 30ms, while in RosyWriter 
its cost is negligible.
what I do is first transform BGR24 to BGRA pixel format, then use CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes function create a CVPixelBufferRef, and then get a CVOpenGLESTextureRef by CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage. My codes as following,

```
- (void)transformBGRToBGRA:(const UInt8 *)pict width:(int)width height:(int)height
{
rgb.data = (void *)pict;

vImage_Error error = vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888(&rgb,NULL,0,&argb,NO,kvImageNoFlags);
if (error != kvImageNoError) {
    NSLog(@"vImageConvert_RGB888toARGB8888 error");
}

const uint8_t permuteMap[4] = {1,2,3,0};

error = vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(&argb,&bgra,permuteMap,kvImageNoFlags);
if (error != kvImageNoError) {
    NSLog(@"vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888 error");
}

free((void *)pict);
}
```

and after transform, will generate CVPixelBufferRef, codes as following,

```
[self transformBGRToBGRA:pict width:width height:height];

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
CVReturn err = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(NULL,
                             width,
                             height,
                             kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, 
                             (void*)bgraData, 
                             bytesByRow, 
                             NULL, 
                             0,
                             NULL, 
                             &pixelBuffer);

if(!pixelBuffer || err)
{
    NSLog(@"CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes failed (error: %d)", err);  
    return;
}

CVOpenGLESTextureRef texture = NULL;
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                            videoTextureCache,
                                                            pixelBuffer,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                            GL_RGBA,
                                                            width,
                                                            height,
                                                            GL_BGRA,
                                                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                            0,
                                                            &texture);


if (!texture || err) {
    NSLog(@"CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed (error: %d)", err);  
    CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
    return;
}
```

The other codes is almost similar RosyWriter sample, include shaders. So I want to know why, 
how to fix this problem.

Comment: What size is the image you are trying to upload? Are you sure that you're not measuring the time of your `-transformBGRToBGRA:` method in that 30 ms?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.It is 1024 * 768, the time of transformBGRToBGRA: I have measured is 10ms.

Comment: OK, so the 30 ms that you measure is from right before the `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes()` call to right after the `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` call? That seems extremely high, because I've seen an iPad 2 upload 1080p frames (2.6X more pixels) much faster than in 30 ms. What are your times if you just use `glTexImage2D()` with this data?

Comment: It is really high, in fact the 30ms is got only call **CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()**,the function **CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes()** cost nothing. I just rewrite codes with **glTexImage2D()**, it costs about 5ms, so I think this is also higher ,I spend more than one day to find why, and try to resolve this problem, but no answer.

Comment: Seemly I find the answer, could you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With my research in these day, I find why `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` cost much time, when the data is big, here is 3M, the **allocation, copy and move operation** which cost is considerable, especially Copy operation. Then with **pixel buffer pool** greatly improve performance of `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` from 30ms to 5ms, the same level with glTexImage2D(). My solution as following:

```
NSMutableDictionary*     attributes;
attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:videoWidth] forKey: (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:videoHeight] forKey: (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey];

CVPixelBufferPoolCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, (CFDictionaryRef) attributes, &bufferPool);

CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer (NULL,bufferPool,&pixelBuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer,0);

UInt8 * baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);

memcpy(baseAddress, bgraData, bytesByRow * videoHeight);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer,0);
```

with this new created **pixelBuffer** you can make it fast.

Add following configures to **attribtes** can make its performance to the best, less than 1ms.

```
 NSDictionary *IOSurfaceProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"IOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibility",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility",nil];

[attributes setObject:IOSurfaceProperties forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey];
```

Comment: I implemented this suggestion, adding the surface properties and making use of a pixel buffer pool. But, I am seeing no improvement in the performance on an iPad2. Now my code just runs memcpy() 89% of the time. I do not see how this approach could improve things, since the texture upload is the time critical part of this code. If the pixel data is already sitting in a user buffer, what would be gained by doing another copy to move the memory into a CVPixelBuffer ?

Comment: Same question here. If you've already got BGRA data in memory, why can't you just wrap this with a CVPixelBufferRef?