# Create a CVPixelBufferRef with OpenGLCompatibility

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, opengl-es

I am trying to create a CVPixelBuffer to allocate a bitmap in it and bind it to an OpenGL texture under IOS 5, but I having some problems on it. I can generate the pixel buffer but the IOSurface is always null, so I can not use it with CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage. Since I am not using a Camera or a Video, but an self generated bitmap I can not use CVSampleBufferRef to get the pixel buffer from it.

I let you my code in case some of you knows how to solve this issue.

```
CVPixelBufferRef renderTarget = nil;
CFDictionaryRef empty; // empty value for attr value.
CFMutableDictionaryRef attrs;
empty = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, // our empty IOSurface properties dictionary
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           0,
                           &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                           &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
attrs = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                  2,
                                  &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                  &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(attrs,
                     kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey,
                     empty);
CFDictionarySetValue(attrs, kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]);

CVReturn err = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, tmpSize.width, tmpSize.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, imageData, tmpSize.width*4, 0, 0, attrs, &renderTarget);
```

If I dump the new PixelBufferRef I get:

```
1 : <CFString 0x3e43024c [0x3f8f8650]>{contents = "OpenGLCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3f8f8a10 [0x3f8f8650]>{value = true}
2 : <CFString 0x3e43026c [0x3f8f8650]>{contents = "IOSurfaceProperties"} = <CFBasicHash 0xa655750 [0x3f8f8650]>{type = immutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}

}
```

And I get an -6683 error (kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible) if I try to use it with a TextureCache, this way:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage (
                                              kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              self.eagViewController.textureCache,
                                              renderTarget,
                                              nil, // texture attributes
                                              GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                              GL_RGBA, // opengl format
                                              tmpSize.width,
                                              tmpSize.height,
                                              GL_BGRA, // native iOS format 
                                              GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                              0,
                                              &renderTextureTemp);
```

Comment: You might want to try out the code from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607753/cvopenglestexturecachecreatetexturefromimage-on-ipad2-is-too-slow-it-needs-almo , particularly the pixel buffer improvements for performance in their answer.